# $post method using in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a "add" button in my jQuery calculator. When I click "add" button, it display "+" in the display and the number that I have entered will be stored. After that I can input another number to finish the equation. I can stuck in the part of the add button not sure how to do it. Do I need to use load()?

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question.  Is something in your code not working?  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected results?  Where are you stuck and how can we help?

Comment: Additional to David: Where is your php-code and why do you wanna do the calculation in PHP and not directly with js?

Comment: Ignore the php part. I want to make a "add" button to stored the data and $ post it php. However, I get stuck in that add button. I don't know what i need to do. Do i need to use load(). ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Made a solution with limited inputs you have given

http://jsfiddle.net/sabkaraja/utc7f2ex/

You can decide what you want to do with the added value in #add.click(....) event. I have used a simple eval to get the result in.

```
 $(function () {
     var $display = $('#display');
     $display.val(0);


     $(document).on('click', 'button.number', function () {
         if ($display.val().length >= 8) {
             $display.val("Error");
         } else if ($display.val() == "Error") {
             $display.val("0");
         } else {
            $display.val( $display.val() + '+' + $(this).val());

         }
     });
     $("#clear").click(function () {
         $display.val("0");
     });
     $("#ce").click(function () {
         if ($display.val().length >= 2) {
             $display.val($display.val().substring(0, $display.val().length - 1));
         } else {
             $("#ce").trigger("click");
         }
     });

     $("#add").click(function () {
         if ($display.val().length !== 0) {
             v = eval($display.val()); //<----- here is where I add the numbers
             $display.val( v); //------------> do whatever you like to do after this
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'submit.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType :'html',
                    data: {sum: v},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
             });
         }
     });
 });
```